# php include path errors: Same code works on Ubuntu default Apache and php conf, but not on CentOS

Tags: apache-2.2, php, centos

So the same code works on my Ubuntu server but when I upload it to my dedicated hosting server running CentOS it seems to add an extra prefix of `.:/usr/share/pear:/usr/share/php:`
I tried setting `includepath` to different things but it just doesn't work. The file is in a directory called language in the same folder as the file that is including it and I'm using:

```
include dirname(__FILE__).DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR."language".DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR."storage.inc";
include dirname(__FILE__)."/language/language.php";
include "language/language.php";
```

and a lot of other combinations but I can't get it to find the file. I keep receiving the error message:

```
Fatal error: require_once() [function.require]: Failed opening required '/home/neo/public_html/migration/include/class/core/storage.inc' (include_path='.:/usr/share/pear:/usr/share/php:/home/neo/public_html/migration') in /home/neo/public_html/migration/include/class/core/class_lang.inc on line 153
```

Comment: Something else is wrong here. The extra include paths aren't causing this, because the include path is not used when you specific an absolute path to include, as you do now.

Answer (score 2):

Whenever I have something bizarrely not working on CentOS, the first thing to check is selinux. It's a security system on by default, and it stops programs accessing files anywhere they haven't been given explicit permissions.

You can either look in

```
/var/log/secure or maybe /var/log/audit/audit.log
```

for deny messages, or you can test by turning selinux off temporarily with

```
echo 0 >/selinux/enforce
```

then testing - but turn it back on later with

```
echo 1 >/selinux/enforce
```

and work out how to adjust it to let it work properly.